# UrlMappings not returning 405 for different URLs on same controller

Tags: grails, url-mapping

I wrote a REST controller, and I want to allow DELETE on the controller for /rest/id, but not /rest/.  Here's my UrlMappings:

```
"/rest"(controller: "restController", parseRequest: true) {
  action = [GET: "list", POST: "save"]
}

"/rest/$id"(controller: "restController", parseRequest: true) {
  action = [GET: "show", PUT: "update", DELETE: "delete"]
}
```

I would expect to get "method not allowed"/405 when my DELETE request hits /rest, but I get a 404.  I thought maybe the request was getting translated to /rest/0, but it's not hitting a breakpoint I put in the delete method of the controller.

Any idea why it works this way, or things I could look at to troubleshoot the issue?

Comment: that's the way it works.  But there is debate about how it *should* work here:
http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-5995

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's a bit ambiguos since grails gets the 405s from the allowedMethods closure of the controller.

Since there is no mapping to DELETE for rest/, the framework is returning a 404, which seems to be correct.

The documentation seems to want you to do something like

```
delete(Long id) {
  if(!id){
    response.sendError 405
  } else {
    ...
  }
}
```

http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/allowedMethods.html

Might be worth raising a JIRA if you don't think this behaviour is correct. From the tests in grails-core, it doesn't seem to be dealing with 405s at all.

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't really work because it doesn't seem to be hitting the delete() method, since it isn't mapped. That seems a little crazy to me... if it's not in the action mappings then it's not an allowed method. Thanks. JIRA it is, we'll see what the answer is.